# Embedding one field to the form

Tags: php, symfony

I have two tables - `products`, and `product_photos`. They are in 1:1 relation. I create the form based on `products` table (using doctrine ORM). But I wanna add one field from `product_photos` table - and how can I do that?

```
    public function editProductDataAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        // entity manager
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        // repository
        $r = $em->getRepository('AdminBundle:Product');

        // entity handler
        $product = $r->find($id);

        $form = $this->createForm(new EditCommonType(), new Product(),
        [
            'action'          => $this->generateUrl('product_edit', ['id' => $id]),
            'attr'            => ['class' => 'stdform', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
            'repository_name' => 'AdminBundle:Product'
        ]);

        $form->add('productPhoto', new ProductPhotoType());

        $form->add('save', 'submit', ['attr' => ['class' => 'submit radius2']]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        //...
}
```

Entities are unchanged. FormTypes either. Twig file:

```
{% form_theme form 'AdminBundle::common_edit_form.html.twig' %} 
{{ form(form) }}
{{ form.productPhoto.photoName }} {# photoName - column from productPhoto table #}
```

Right now, I'm getting `Method "productPhoto" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in AdminBundle:Product:edit.html.twig at line 23` error, which is in the last line in twig code above.

If you need more code, type it in the comments please.

Comment: Could you please post the code of your `EditCommonType` and `ProductPhotoType`?

Comment: Are you just wanting to display the photo name or are you wanting to add a field to the form to edit the name?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
{{form(form.productPhoto.vars.prototype.name)}}
```